# How do I configure clang_complete for linux kernel module development?

Tags: c, linux, vim, clang, kernel-module

I tried to get gcc to [dump the include paths](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/pipermail/splint-discuss/2004-October/000500.html) and my [`.clang_complete`](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/blob/master/doc/clang_complete.txt) file now looks like:

```
-std=gnu89
-nostdinc
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/arch/x86/include
-I/lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/arch/x86/include/generated
-I/lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include
-I/lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/ubuntu/include
-I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
-D__KERNEL__
-DMODULE
```

But `libclang` still complains tons of errors & warnings when editing a simple hello world kernel module.

```
1 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|24 col 42 warning| declaration of 'struct list_head' will not be visible outside of this function
2 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|26 col 6 error| incomplete definition of type 'struct list_head'
3 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|24 col 42 info| forward declaration of 'struct list_head'
4 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|27 col 6 error| incomplete definition of type 'struct list_head'
5 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|24 col 42 info| forward declaration of 'struct list_head'
6 /lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include/linux/list.h|37 col 38 warning| declaration of 'struct list_head' will not be visible outside of this function
...
```

the definition of `struct list_head` from `<linux/types.h>` is already included by `<linux/list.h>`. Both are inside `/lib/modules/3.0.0-16-generic/build/include`

Answer (score 4):

The cc_args.py bundled with clang_complete could have been useful to you. It should build a valid .clang_complete file. Unfortunately (I've just tested it, and I will try to fix it), it doesn't work here (the .clang_complete file could not be created).

However, by tweaking the script and its result, I've been able to produce a valid .clang_complete file :

```
-D__KERNEL__
-DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1
-DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1
-DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1
-DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1
-nostdinc
-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/include
-I/usr/src/linux-3.2.12-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include
-I/usr/src/linux-3.2.12-1-ARCH/arch/x86/include/generated
-I/usr/src/linux-3.2.12-1-ARCH/include
-DMODULE
-DKBUILD_STR(s)=#s
-include /usr/src/linux-3.2.12-1-ARCH/include/linux/kconfig.h
```

With this .clang_complete, there is only one error left, related to __kfree_rcu, for more information about it, see : https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/12/2